# Material ui TextField not editable in React

Tags: reactjs

TextField not working, i want  to increase and decrease the value of textfield on Increment and decrement, And when i click on addToCart button, i want that textfield input value as well along with items(object)  addtocart  button

`value` and `defualtValue` props not working

```
<Button  onClick={() => decrement(items.id)}>Decrement</Button>
<TextField value={items.quantity}/> 
<Button  onClick={() => decrement(items.id)}>Increment</Button>

<Button  onClick={() => addTocart(items)}>Add to cart</Button>
```

items has item `{ id: 4, productname: 'Grapes', price: 100, quantity: 1 }`

```
const addToCart = (newItem) => {
   want input value and  item object
}
```

Comment: Please declare "items" variable as a state variable. So when "items" is changed, use setItems function.

Comment: Declare the `items` state variable using `useState` hook or class variable.

Comment: What and were is `items` declared? Can you share a more comprehensive code example?

Comment: const allProducts=[
    { id:1, productName:'Apple',price:100,quantity:1}
    { id:2, productName:'Cherry',price:70,quantity:1}
    { id:3, productName:'Orange',price:60,quantity:1}
    { id:4, productName:'Grapes',price:69,quantity:1}
]
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, allProducts)

{ state.map(item=>(

Comment: Can you share your `reducer` function and the `increment` and `decrement` action creators? The value for the text field will update so long as you are updating the state correctly. Can you clarify what you want when the "add to cart" button is clicked? Is your question about incrementing/decrementing an item count, or is it about adding a new item to your state? Can you "walk" us through your UI/UX and what should happen when and for what reason?

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code.

```
const [items, setItems] = React.useState({id:4, productname:'Grapes', price:100, quantity:1});

...

<Button  onClick={()=>setItems({...items, quantity: items.quantity - 1})} > Decrement</Button>
<TextField value={items.quantity}/> 
<Button  onClick={()=>setItems({...items, quantity: items.quantity + 1})} > Increment</Button>
```